# SymPy cannot solve polynomial equation of 4th order

Tags: python, sympy, polynomial-math, equation-solving

I have an polynomial equation of 4th order and I need to find all roots. 
Simple example:

```
from sympy import (Symbol,solve,I)

a=4+5*I; b=3+7*I; c=12-56*I; d=33+56*I; e=345-67*I; x=Symbol('x')
eq=a*x**4 + b*x**3 + c*x**2 + d*x +e
solve(eq,x)
```

If a,b,c,d,e are pure real, then
it work just fine. 
But in my case all of them are complex numbers. Then i did get call:

```
PolynomialError: 'cannot return general quartic solution'
```

I find kind of similar issue, and implement the fix:
[Description of the issue](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/7102).
[Fix of the issue](https://github.com/smichr/sympy/commit/a0417388907f43d0f8f031430212d05a4aa8f2f3#diff-d894f081abd575157b2fb8a00da805fcR494)

but it doesn't really help. There is some kind of strange problem, as now the call is (as changed in the fix):

```
PolynomialError: Cannot determine if `-((12 - 56*I)/(4 + 5*I) - 3*(3 + 7*I)**2/(8*(4 + 5*I)**2))**2/12 + (3 + 7*I)*((33 + 56*I)/(4*(4 + 5*I)) + (3 + 7*I)*(3*(3 + 7*I)**2/(256*(4 + 5*I)**2) - (12 - 56*I)/(16*(4 + 5*I)))/(4 + 5*I))/(4 + 5*I) - (345 - 67*I)/(4 + 5*I)` is nonzero.
```

But to determine if expression above is nonzero is the most simplest thing, so don't know where the problem could be.

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade to the most recent version of SymPy which supports arbitrary quartic solutions.

Comment: After i update to sympy 0.7.6 (using python 3.4) there is different error massage: line 103 in __nonzero__ : raise TypeError("cannot determine truth value of\n%s" % self)

Comment: Looks like this is a bug, which has been fixed in the git version of SymPy.

Comment: I'm using anaconda distribution of python. Is it possible to update somehow to this git version there, or i have to rewrite some scripts?

Comment: Install git (on OS X and Windows the easiest way is to install the GitHub desktop client), clone https://github.com/sympy/sympy, and use `python setup.py install` or `python setup.py develop` (the latter will automatically update if you do a git pull, otherwise you have to install it again each time). Or if you only use isympy, you can just cd to the sympy directory and run `bin/isympy` from there.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a more flexible solution, you could solve for x using binary search with something like the following:

```
def maybeRightX(maybeX, polys):
    sum = 0
    for i in range(len(polys)):
        sum += polys[i]*(maybeX ** i)
    return sum

def solve(y, polys):
    lo = 0
    hi = y
    while lo <= hi:
        mid = (lo + hi)//2
        if (maybeRightX(mid, polys)) < y:
            lo = mid + 1
        else:
            hi = mid - 1
    return (hi + 1)
```